# Custom signature appears twice on page

Tags: plugin-development, filters, the-content

I have a simple plugin which adds a signature at the end of each post. But it also appears after user comment section. How to avoid the latter?

**Update**

I have tried to run the function once by adding a static variable. Now signature is just adding to comment section. I need exactly the reverse. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
/*
header...
*/

if( !function_exists("add_signature")){
    function add_signature($content){

    /* code related to update
    static $once;

    if ( $once !== null )
            return $content;
        else
            $once = 'done';
    */

        if( !is_page() )
            return $content . "signature";
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'add_signature');
}

?>
```

Comment: From your code sample you are appending it to the the_content() function. If your comments template is using the_content() in any way this could be why its duplicating. If you want it to appear on every post page, I would build it into the template rather than appending it to the_content().

Comment: @EBennett: If that's the case i should avoid adding signature when comment section is already added to content. I 've tried checking `strpos($content, 'comment_form') == false` before adding signature but still signature is printed twice.

Comment: I have tried other themes like the built-in ones and problem didn't solve.

Comment: Could you update your example to include code for your template files where this is happening? This will allow for a better understanding of how you are using this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_post_type() to check which content you're appending your signature to.

```
function add_signature($content){
    if( get_post_type() == 'post' )
        return $content . "signature";
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_signature');
```

Comment: still twice. on at the end of post and one after comment section

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_signature' );

function add_signature( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() &&  get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        return $content .  "signature";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code in additon to posting it.

Comment: with this constrain applied, nothing is added neither to post nor to comment section because  `in_the_loop()` is always false in my case.